# How can I create custom colors in Tailwind CSS using a theme config file in Next.js with TypeScript?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS with Next.js and TypeScript, and I want to set up a theme configuration file in the root directory that contains custom color codes. Then, I want to import that theme configuration from `tailwind.config.js` to create custom colors. Is it possible to do this?

I've tried creating a `theme.ts` file in the root directory that exports an object with the custom color codes, like this:

```js
// theme.ts
export const theme = {
  colors: {
    primary: '#FF0000',
    secondary: '#00FF00',
  },
};
```

And then importing this in `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

import { theme } from './theme';

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: theme.colors.primary,
        secondary: theme.colors.secondary,
        // add more custom colors here
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

But when I try to run the project, I get the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` for the import statement in `tailwind.config.js`.

How can I properly set up a theme configuration file that can be imported in `tailwind.config.js` with Next.js and TypeScript?

Comment: Your `tailwind.config.js` has an `import` _and_ a `module.exports` - is it ESM or CommonJS?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, do you mean module in `tsconfig.json`?  it's `"module": "esnext",`

Comment: No I mean which do you think _that file_ is? Do you have `"type":` set in `package.json`? If you're emitting `"module": "esnext"` it should be `"type": "module"` but the error suggests you have nothing or `"type": "commonjs"`.

Comment: I haven't setup `"type" :` in `package.json`

Comment: Change your theme.ts to theme.js and do `module.exports = theme`. Also, in the tailwind config, you need to use require() instead of import